# XOR strings of bytes

Tags: python, encryption

I want to XOR two strings of bytes and I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between these two pieces of code, the last one works, but I dont understand why one does and the other doesn't. I've also tried with bytes object but doesn't work either.

```
    resultado3 = bytearray(len(ab))
    for byte1, byte2 in zip(ab, bb):
      resultado3 += bytearray(byte1 ^ byte2)

    resultado2 = bytes([ x^y for (x,y) in zip(ab, bb)])
```

Being my two inputs:
**ab = 1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c** and **bb = 686974207468652062756c6c277320657965** and the outputs when I print them:
**resultado2 = b"the kid don't play"** and **resultado3 = bytearray(b'\x00 ..... \x00')** (all filled with zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: `bytearray(n)` returns a zero-initialized bytearray of length `n`. So when you did `resultado3 += bytearray(byte1 ^ byte2)` you are effectively concatenating all-null bytearray of some length to your `resultado3`.

To achieve your intended purpose, use `resultado3 += bytearray([byte1 ^ byte2])` instead (note the list of one element).

Comment: `resultado3` is also initialized incorrectly for the same reason.